# liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: [SQL7008]

Tags: db2, liquibase, db2-400

Reason:

> liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: [SQL7008] MIG1 in CARSTDATA not
> valid for operation.

got this error when trying to insert it into the table that I created.

The table exists but I am unable to insert the data. its a Db2 for i series (AS/400).

Comment: Did you check the docs?  See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzaii/rzaiiodbc45.htm

Comment: If you are trying to use transactions, then you'll need to have journaling enabled for the file.  The easiest way is to create an SQL collection -- CREATE COLLECTION MIG2.  Then create the table in MIG2.

Comment: if the table is not journalised, you must change the ODBC datasource and add: TxnIsolation= 32  (NOCOMMIT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the file contains a foreign key the most common problem is that no journaling is enabled on the file. If this is your case you have to enable journaling like this:

```cl
strJrnPf yourLib/carsdata jrn(yourLib/yourJournal)
```

Then you can use commitment control as @mshabou stated above.